# Is it possible to inject a next.js component into an existing application (html + css + vanilla javascript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Currently I build an SDK that renders a React component into a legacy site that uses mainly HTML, CSS and plain javascript + jquery.

I do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  const configuration = {...}
  app.loadElement(configuration, wrapper); 
})
```

And on the SDK part I defined a method named `loadElement` that's something like this:

```
function loadElement(configuration, wrapper) {
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Element, { ...props }), wrapper);
}
```

Any ideas if there are any ways that I can improve this approach?
Are there any other libraries that does a better job for this particular use-case?
Can I adopt next.js for this use case?

Comment: By Next.js component, do you mean a regular React component? There's no such thing as a Next.js component - unless you're specifically talking about Next.js built-in components like `next/image` or `next/link`, but those would require Next.js to work.